# How to add pincodes in magento? does it need any extension packs?

Tags: php, magento

This question may seems like out of the rules, But need assitance from experts.

Im not an experienced Magento - developer, So we had signed an agreement with another developer for our new E-commerce website,

Im from India and I have all the pin-code lists by states. I have experience in php development but not in Magento.

My requirement is to add pin-codes to our websites for usual COD availability check, When i contacted the developer they said that they need an extension pack for achieving this. is this the right method?

I wonder why doesn't it possible to check the pin-code entered by user is the one we have in COD list (thinking about general programming), awaiting reply from experts

Comment: You're not getting an answer here mate.

Comment: @Daan As i expected :), But, i just need an answer, a Yes or No for my question, is it possible without extension packs? Thats all  what i need.

Comment: No I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @Shan I was also looking for the same thing and ended up creating a custom extension. I am also not an expert in Magento, but if you need I can share with you how I created the extension.

Comment: @James thanks for your reply,& pls share the idea !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is the perfect solution, but this is how I did it.

First create a module for the database table for the list of COD pincode.
This is the article I referred to create this module http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm.

Now you have to create another module to carry out Ajax call. I don't remember the article which I referred to create this module, so will share my module details. Lets call the module **AjaxBlock**.
To understand how to create a custom module in Magento please refer this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

List of files for the AjaxBlock module:

1. app/etc/modules/Namespace_AjaxBlock.xml
2. app/code/local/Namespace/AjaxBlock/etc/config.xml
3. app/code/local/Namespace/AjaxBlock/controllers/IndexController.php

`config.xml` content

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
          <ajaxblock>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
              <module>Namespace_AjaxBlock</module>
              <frontName>ajaxblock</frontName>
            </args>
          </ajaxblock>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
```

And this is how the `IndexController.php` will look like

```
class Namespace_AjaxBlock_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $pinCode=$_POST['pincodeValue']; // pincode entered by the user

        // Validation for pin code
        if (!preg_match("/^\d{6}$/i",$pinCode)){
            //Validation failed, provided zip/postal code is not valid.
            $result="Please enter a valid pincode.";
        }else{
            //Validation passed, provided zip/postal code is valid.
            // This is model for COD pincode database table, change it to your resource model name. This filters the table with the pincode entered by the user
            $model = Mage::getModel('<module>/<module>')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('pincode', $pinCode);
            if(empty($model)){ // the collection will be empty if the pincode entered by the user is not present in the database table
                $result="COD not available";
            }else{
                $result="COD available";
            }

        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody($result);
    }
}
```

I wanted the pincode checker in the product page. So I added the below code in the product page phtml file. You can add this code where you want the pincode checker to be shown.

```
<div class="pincode-check">
    <p class="pincode-title">Check Cash on delivery availability</p>
    <input type="text" name="pin" id="pin-input" placeholder ="Enter your pincode" />
    <button id="submit-pin">Check</button>
    <p id="message"></p>
</div>

    <!-- Ajax Block-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pincodeValue = $j( "#pin-input" ).val();
        $j( "#submit-pin" ).click(function(){
            pincodeValue = $j( "#pin-input" ).val();
            $j('#message').hide();
            // alert(pincodeValue);
            $j.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajaxblock/index/index') ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                pincodeValue:pincodeValue,},
            success: function(data) {
                $j('#message').show();
                $j('#message').html(data);
                },
            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });   
        });       
    </script>
```

Comment: Accepted as the answer , since you cleared my doubt and provided some ideas.. thanks